# In a commutative ring without identity, is $\left(a\right)\left(b\right)=\left(ab\right)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring and let $a,b \in R$. If $R$ is commutative and doesn't necessarily have an identity, is there an equality of ideals: $\left(a\right)\left(b\right)=\left(ab\right)$ ?

If $R$ is any general ring, then $\left(ab\right)\subseteq\left(a\right)\left(b\right)$ since $\left(a\right)\left(b\right)$ is an ideal which contains $ab$. I am not sure about the reverse inclusion $\left(a\right)\left(b\right)\subseteq\left(ab\right)$ for a commutative ring. It is not hard to show that the reverse inclusion holds when $R$ is commutative and has identity, but for the case where $R$ is commutative and does not have an identity, I am not sure.

Here is my starting point: Every element of $\left(a\right)\left(b\right)$ is a finite sum of elements of the form $\left[r_{i}a+n_{i}\cdot a\right]\left[s_{i}b+m_{i}\cdot b\right]$, where $r_{i},s_{i}\in R$ and $n_{i},m_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}$ and every element of $\left(ab\right)$ will be of the form $rab+p\cdot ab$ for some $p\in\mathbb{Z}$, so it suffices to show that for any given $r,s\in R$ and $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}$, there exist $t\in R$ and $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\left[ra+n\cdot a\right]\left[sb+m\cdot b\right]=tab+p\cdot ab$. I tried expanding the left hand side expression to get it in the form of the right hand side expression, but I wasn't able to progress much with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the obstacle to evaluating $\left[ra+n\cdot a\right]\left[sb+m\cdot b\right]$ was, but it's just a lot of applications of the distributive property:

$$\left[ra+n\cdot a\right]\left[sb+m\cdot b\right] = (rs+n\cdot s+m\cdot r)ab + (nm)\cdot ab$$

Comment: Embarassing that I didn't figure this out, but I'll take it.